# JMeter Webdriver sampler "WaitForText"

Tags: webdriver, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I wonder if someone can help, as I can't work this out, I am wanting to use WebDriver Sampler in JMeter and am getting stuck working out a `WaitForText`.

I want to wait for "Complete" in the element `//tr[6]/td[2]/strong`, this is what I have, but it isn't working and I'm not sure why, hope someone can help:

```
wait.until("Complete".presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//tr[6]/td[2]/strong")).getText())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what programming language you use, the below answer assumes default WebDriver Sampler language which is JavaScript.

You should implement your own custom [Function](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Function.html) like

```
var wait = new org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 10)
WaitForText = function() {
    var text = WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath('//tr[6]/td[2]/strong')).getText()    
    return text.equals('Complete')
}
wait.until(new com.google.common.base.Function(WaitForText))
```

For more WebDriver Sampler related tips and tricks refer to [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) guide

Comment: Thank you so much for this, you have really helped me :)